# Mock HttpPostedFileBase ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking, httppostedfilebase

Trying to mock upload file.

This is controller side

```
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        try
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(@"c:\work\",
             Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
            file.SaveAs(path);
            ViewBag.Message = "File uploaded successfully";
```

This is unit test side

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod()
{
    Mock<ControllerContext> cc = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
    HomeController c = new HomeController()
    {
        ControllerContext = cc.Object
    };
    c.ControllerContext.RouteData = new RouteData();
    UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();
    Mock<HttpPostedFileBase> file1 = new Mock<HttpPostedFileBase>();
    var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
    file1.SetupGet(d => d.FileName).Returns("listebv.txt");
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(enc.GetBytes(@"C:\work\listebv.txt"));
    file1.SetupGet(d => d.InputStream).Returns( ms);
    file1.SetupGet(d => d.ContentLength).Returns((int)ms.Length);
    file1.SetupGet(d => d.ContentType).Returns("text/plain");
    cc.SetupGet(d => d.HttpContext.Request.Files.Count).Returns(1);
    cc.SetupGet(d => d.HttpContext.Request.Files[0]).Returns(file1.Object);

    c.Index(file1.Object);
```

When I launch the test, `file.SaveAs (path)` doesn't work (no file created)
and no error was returned

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You're passing in a mock object. That mock object does not actually save the file. You should look to verify that SaveAs was called on the mock with the expected value.

```
file1.Verify(f => f.SaveAs(@"c:\work\listebv.txt"));
```

Comment: ty for help. your code works and its ok ! but i dont understand why the file is not created in destination c:\work\lupload\istebv.txt

Comment: @als that's not the way mocks work. Mocks don't actually implement the behavior. They don't do the thing, they give you a way to tell (via `Verify`) that the call was made.